# Ubuntu server: www not found

Tags: 14.04, dns, bind

I configured my server bind db.mydomain.com with:

```
mydomain.com.           IN      MX  10  mail.vumila.com.
mydomain.com.           IN      A       192.192.192.82
www.mydomain.com        IN      A       192.192.192.82
ns1                     IN      A       192.192.192.82
ns2                     IN      A       192.192.192.81
www                     IN      A       mydomain.com.
www                     IN      CNAME   mydomain.com.
mail                    IN      A       216.172.176.82
ftp                     IN      CNAME   mydomain.com.
```

It worked for mydomain.com, but not with www.mydomain.com, and when I dig www.mydomain.com I got answer = 0 . What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

**If you put an A Resouce Record (RR) you have to write a ipv4 address.**
     A   A host address. In the IN class, this is a 32-bit IP address.
     Page 124 http://www.bind9.net/arm910.pdf

**I guest that you have a $ORIGIN at first with mydomain.com.**
      $ORIGIN mydomain.com.
      WWW CNAME MAIN-SERVER is equivalent to
      WWW.EXAMPLE.COM. CNAME MAIN-SERVER.EXAMPLE.COM.

**I think you don't need cname RR. That is for an alias but from what I see you only have your mydomain.**

**This is an example:**

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$ORIGIN mydomain.com.
$TTL    604800


@       IN  NS  ns.mydomain.com.
@       IN  MX  0 smtp.mydomain.com
        IN  A   192.168.56.102
        ns      IN  A   192.168.56.102
        www     IN  A   192.168.56.102
        www1        IN  A   192.168.56.101
        pop     IN  A   192.168.56.102
        smtp        IN  A   192.168.56.102
        imap        IN  A   192.168.56.102
        ldap        IN  A   192.168.56.102
        ftp     IN  A   192.168.56.102
```

Comment: Thanks, but dig still giving  UERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
 www IN A mydomain.com.
```

Is your problem line.

I'm pretty sure you just need the

```
 www.mydomain.com IN A 192.192.192.82
```

Other than that, everything looks good I think